# How to create .mx file from .m file in Mathematica?

Tags: packages

I want to generate .mx file from .m file on linux system.
I tried using Export function which generated the .mx file.But the generated file did not get loaded using the GET function.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Look up `DumpSave[]`.

Comment: or `Export[..., "mx"]` if you want to store data not symbols.

Comment: I want create binary mx file which I can load on linux machine using GET function.But DumpSave is takinf .m file as input parameter as it needs object.